# Can I execute the output of this current query, which is itself a query automatically?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is my query. The output of this query is a query that I can then execute as needed, but I don't want to continue doing so manually. I used to have this query within a manual process, but I now have the need to generate the output of the query that is generated on demand to send the results over to another DB for reporting purposes. What's the best approach to have the output of this existing query automatically execute? Is there a way I can do so without creating a function?

I appreciate any help in advance. Thanks

```
with full_query_parts as (
    select distinct 
         format(' select first_year."Id" 
                       , case ''%2$s'' when ''Table1'' then ''GL'' when 
                     ''Table2'' then ''HC'' when ''Table3'' then ''OPP'' 
                         else ''REV'' end                     as "Resource" 
                       , extract(''year'' from "%3$s")   as "Year" 
                       , count(*)                        as "TxnCount" 
              from %1$s."%2$s" 
                  left join (select "Id" 
                                  , extract(''year'' from "CreatedAt") as year_0             
                         from app."Companies" 
                             where "Id"::VARCHAR = split_part(''%1$s'', '''', 
                          ''3'') ) first_year on true 
                  group by 1, 2, 3'
                  ,table_schema,table_name,column_name) as que 
         from information_schema.columns 
         where table_schema 
             in ( select distinct regexp_replace( 
                      'company_schema'||"Id", '[^\w ,]', '', 'g') as company 
    from app."Companies" ) 
    and (table_name = 'Table1' and column_name = 'Date') 
    or  (table_name = 'Table2' and column_name = 'Date') 
    or  (table_name = 'Table3' and column_name = 'CreatedDate') 
    or  (table_name = 'Table4' and column_name = 'CreatedDate') 
    or  (table_name = 'Table5' and column_name = 'CreatedDate') ) 
select string_agg(que,' union all ') from full_query_parts;
```

Also wanted to confirm the reason why I'm going through information_schema is because not each table exists in each of the company specific schemas in the Postgres DB..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can..!

via `psql` , output of the query can be executed in automated way by the meta command `\gexec`.

Here is the example:

postgres# `select 'select deptid,deptname from mstdepartment'; \gexec;`